# Correct way to restart application with Activiti workflow

Tags: activiti, bpmn

I use Activiti framework in my application. Activiti is managed via Activiti API.

***What a problem:***

I need to restart server wtih application. This means two things:

1. I need to suspend/stop all active activities correctly
2. I need to renew all stopped activities correctly

At the moment my application is stopped via *System.exit(0)*

***Question:***

1. *How could I do that? (means two items above)*
2. *What problems I'll faced with System.exit(0)?*

***EDIT:***

1. Yes, thanks. But I use embedded Activiti. Does those applies to embedded or only for standalone (via REST)?
2. What about *async* tasks?
3. I saw ProcessEngine .close function. What it is for? Do I need it?

***EDIT2:***

I make a demo that illustrate the problem with asynchronous task suspending. You can get it by typing:

```
git clone https://github.com/JOLO-/Activiti-Process-Suspend-Renew-Demo.git
```

***About demo:***

I workflow looks like: [Main Process] => [Asyncronous Subprocess] => [Return to Main Process]

Each asyncronous process contains *infiniti loop* that print something each second (*AddCandidateService.java*).

You should look at Main class. There I do next things:

1. Launch two main processes
2. For each main process I launch one asynch subprocess  (with infinite loop)
3. Suspend all active processes

*[Expected result]:*

All processes & subprocesses stop their computations

*[Actual result]:*

**Async subprocesses proceed their computations**

Comment: This question hasn't been closed yet. Please, answer to the EDIT2 section of a question

Answer (score 2):

`Activiti framework`, as you must be knowing, runs and functions solely based on `its database`, that is configured.

So when you start a process then a process instance is created and stored in database, along with current `task` or `activitiy` and other related information. Even if you stop the server and start it again then also the data will be available in database.

Still if you want to suspend and renew activities, then you can do as following :

using `Activiti 5.13`

**List item**

Get all process instances running

`GET runtime/process-instances`, it will list all process instances

**Suspend a instance**

`PUT runtime/process-instances/{processInstanceId}`

Request body is :
`{
   "action":"suspend"
}`

**Renew a instance or activate a process instance**

`PUT runtime/process-instances/{processInstanceId}`

`{
   "action":"activate"
}`

For reference : [us`enter code here`er guide](http://www.activiti.org/userguide)

You can use in embedded also as shown below :

**To suspend a process instance:**

```
RuntimeService runtimeService = processEngine.getRuntimeService();
runtimeService.suspendProcessInstanceById(processInstanceid)
```

**TO Activate a process instance**

```
RuntimeService runtimeService = processEngine.getRuntimeService();
runtimeService.activateProcessInstanceById(processInstanceid)
```

I am not quite sure of `processEngine.close()` method, but i think its like `closing the connection` if you are not going ton use. I have never tried or used that in my applications.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Please, see EDIT section of my question

Comment: No, I didn't. Bvut I'm goint to use it today. Thanks

Comment: All works fine except asynch tasks. They proceed execution after suspend

Comment: see EDIT2 section of my question